# How to unwrap my net to mesh with Shrinkwrap

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Im having the mesh and i want to wrap the net mesh to the face. With the the shrink-wrap i have made the projection also but fail to unwrap. Any help or suggestion to wrap the net on the face clean way. I have always problem with the shrink-wrap.
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have enough faces in the net mesh, and try different methods of projection in Shrink Wrap modifier

Comment: @Georges yeah i tried all 3 options in shrinkwrap but fail to shrink on it.

Comment: I checked the .blend file, you need to use flat mesh for the net with shrink wrap, not 3 dimensional mesh, and you don't have enough geometry in the centralized lines, you need to subdivide them

Comment: by the way, it's better to use texture in this case, even if you want the net to look popping out, you can use bump, or displace.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the good approach to make the net, but, what you can do is helping the shrinkwrap a bit.

- Add a cast modifier, keep it to 'sphere'
- Place the modifier before the shrinkwrap
- Use another object, an empty for instance in place of the sphere center
- Adjust all that, by doing three things: scaling, rotating, changing the sphere factor... so that you obtain a shape around Spiderman's face
- Once done, make the shrinkwrap visible again (and adjust again if needed)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice @lemon , I didn't know about the Cast modifier!

Comment: @lemon Thanks for the reply. The idea was great but after the shrink wrap is visible if zoom and see the lines or net mesh is not clean as its was before visible the shrink wrap. What i was thinking was achieved but the mesh is not clean. Can we do something for that.

Comment: @ateks, what can be tried is to use a flat net (no volume, just surfaces) because the shrinkwrap will flatten all. From that, you can add a solidify modifier after the shrinkwrap to give the net its volume again. But as I said in the response, I'm not sure this is globally the good approach for all that. PS: but what is sure is the closer the net is from the face, the better the sw modifier will work. Other information: if the net is flat, you can also use the 'project' option which could be better to avoid distortions

Comment: @ateks, rapidly modified to check the way using the 'project' option:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4NcY.jpg (here some vertices still need to be removed, but the projection is better)... you may give it a try